# How do I get ClientId with Nodered

Tags: mqtt, node-red, mosquitto

I am running Mosquitto and nodered in the same raspberry, I send succesfully messages to a my MQTT Server and also have created an input node that connects succesfully. I am now trying to get, from the message received, the clientId info. Is there any way to get it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The MQTT protocol does not include any information about who published a message when it gets sent to a subscriber.

You would need to include this information in the topic string or payload the publisher sends.

Comment: When the client connects, it sends the clientId, I guess this info is kept somewhere and could be extracted. In IBM bluemix, for example, they manage con add to msg.payload two parameters, DeviceID and deviceType, that are part of the clientId string when connecting. I was trying to implement something similar with mosquitto. Thanks